# How to make a table to display records from a SQLite database?

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I got a simple question. I am trying to create some kind of layout that would display my records from SQLite Database in separate cells. I tried to make it using TextViews, but it is not what I expect. Do you know any ideas to create 'excel like' table with headers etc? What is more i need each row to be able to select and open (My goal is to have something like catalogue with products).

```
final TextView dTable= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.displayTable);
final ManageDatabase md = new ManageDatabase(this);
 dTable.setText("");
    for(Product p: md.takeAllProducts()){

        dTable.setText(dTable.getText()+"\n"+" "+p.getProductCode()+" "+p.getProductName()+" "+p.getQuantity()+" "+p.getExpireDate());
    }
```

Comment: what does _catalogue with products_ have to do with "excel like"? What exactly is your issue you are facing? What errors do you get? What do you mean by saying _...but it is not what I expect.._ ?

Comment: I mean I want to create table with rows and columns, where I can click on a row and open 'additional info' about product. My issue is that I can only display data from database but in one TextView field. What I expect is something like HTML table which I can put inside inside the loop to display all records.

Comment: You can use a `GridLayout`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `TableLayout` for it and dynamically add your content there.

First get the reference of table layout from XML file.

```
TableLayout myTable = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.mTable);
```

Then you can add retrieved data to the table dynamically like below

```
 for(Product p: md.takeAllProducts()){
         //create new row
         TableRow tableRow =  new TableRow(this);

         // create new text view
         TextView textView1 = new TextView(this);
         textView1.setText(p.getProductCode());
         //add to row
         tableRow.addView(textView1);

         //create another text view and add to same row
         TextView textView2 = new TextView(this);
         textView2.setText(p.getProductName());
         tableRow.addView(textView2);

         //
         TextView textView3 = new TextView(this);
         textView3.setText(p.getQuantity());
         tableRow.addView(textView3);

         //
         TextView textView4 = new TextView(this);
         textView4.setText(p.getExpireDate());
         tableRow.addView(textView4);
}
```